# AngularJS Directive (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to use directives in AngularJS with TypeScript. I have followed a tutorial, where in I followed every step accordingly.. but I ran in to some troubles. For some reason it's not displaying the content of my Directive.

**The directive itself:**

```
module Directives {
    debugger;
    export interface IMyScope extends ng.IScope
    {
        name: string;
    }

    export function LeftMenu(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            template: '<div>{{name}}</div>',
            scope: {},
            link: (scope: IMyScope) => {
                scope.name = 'Aaron';
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now, I placed a debugger to check if my code even runs until it reaches the directive, and yes it does. My chrome is debugging on the point where it is supposed to.

**Registering all directives (even though I have only one atm):**

```
/// <reference path="../reference.ts" />

angular.module('directives', []).directive(Directives)
```

**My reference file:**

```
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/libs/bower_components/definitelytyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/libs/bower_components/definitelytyped/angularjs/angular-route.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../wwwroot/libs/dx-libs/ts/dx.all.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="contollers/controllers.ts" />
/// <reference path="directives/directives.ts" />
/// <reference path="app.ts" />
```

**Calling the directive like this:**

```
<div>
    <left-menu></left-menu>
</div>
```

There are no errors logged what so ever.. So, I hope someone has the solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `angular.module('directives', []).directive(Directives)` don't think this code will work. You register a typescript module, and without any name

Comment: @devqon I'm doing that for my controllers as well and it's working. Also, the debugger starts debugging in my browser. So it means it at least gets into the module.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register a directive with a name as first parameter. This is how I would write your directive in combination with typescript:

```
export = class LeftMenu implements angular.IDirective {
    static ID = "leftMenu";

    public restrict = "AE";
    public template = '<div>{{name}}</div>';
    public scope = {};
    public link = (scope: IMyScope) => {
        scope.name = 'Aaron';
    }

    // to show how to handle injectables
    constructor(private somethingInjected){}

    static factory() {
        // to show how to handle injectables
        var directive = (somethingInjected) => new MyDirective(somethingInjected);
        directive.$inject = ["somethingInjected"];
        return directive;
    }
}
```

and to register it:

```
import leftMenu = require("LeftMenu");

angular.module('directives', []).directive(leftMenu.ID, leftMenu.factory());
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I think you're script is working, but I still can't seem to get the directive shown on my page. How would I do that? I though `<left-menu></left-menu>` would be the trick, but no.. @devqon

Comment: Have you included the 'directives' module in your module where you use it?: `angular.module("myModule", ["directives"]);`

Comment: You still haven't registered the directive with a name, that should be the first parameter in `.directive("leftMenu", leftMenu.factory())`

Comment: It gives me an error in the console now: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=Provider%20%3C-%20%20%3C-%20leftMenuDirective - Also I tried doing the: "import leftMenu = require("LeftMenu");" which didn't work :s

Comment: The error I'm getting on the require is: `Error: Can't find module`.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger fires because you actually submit an object to `.directive` (typescript transpiles modules into objects by default).

You could try to initialize the directive either directly in the file declarating it:

```
angular
    .module("module.a")
    .directive("directive.a", (): angular.IDirective =>
    {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "template.a.html",
            controller: "controller.a",
            controllerAs: "$ctrl",
            link: () => {},
            bindToController: true
        };
    });
```

or simply the exported function

```
angular
    .module("module.a")
    .directive("directive.a", Directives.LeftMenu);
```

I am not aware of a typescript-module-aware version of the `.directive` function of angular, that registeres all directives of a module.